# how to get a submatch of a match in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

> str='< TOPICS>< D>cocoa< /D>< /TOPICS>< PLACES>< D>el-salvador< /D><
>   D>usa< /D>< D>uruguay< /D>< /PLACES>'

I want to get the string between < D> and < /D> in < PLACES> and < /PLACES>.
I have known the flowing:

```
p1=re.compile(r'(?<=<PLACES>)(.*?)(?=</PLACES>)')
p2=re.compile(r'(?<=<D>)(.*?)(?=</D>)')
```

with p1 and p2,I can get el-salvador,usa,uruguay.But how can I get the info with only a **p**.

Comment: Avoid using regular expression and use a Parser.

Comment: [a must-read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this one:

```
(?<=<D>)([^<>]*)(?=</D>)(?=(?:(?!<PLACES>).)*</PLACES>)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/cO7cH2)

Where the positive lookahead `(?=(?:(?!<PLACES>).)*</PLACES>)` makes sure there's a `</PLACES>` somewhere ahead, without any opening `<PLACES>` in between what is matched and that closing tag.

But you really should consider using a proper parser, such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> text = '<TOPICS><D>cocoa</D></TOPICS><PLACES><D>el-salvador</D><D>usa</D><D>uruguay</D></PLACES>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> for m in soup.find_all('d'):
...     if m.parent.name == 'places':
...         print(''.join(m))
...
el-salvador
usa
uruguay
```

**EDIT**: As suggested by JonClements in the comments, you can also use:

```
>>> for m in soup.select('places d'):
...     print(''.join(m))
...
el-salvador
usa
uruguay
```

Comment: Alternatively, use select... `for m in soup.select('places d')`

Comment: @JonClements Awesome!

Comment: I don't want to parse the whole xml,but only the text in some specified label.I think Regex is faster.Thanks for your advice.:)